# How to change my interval within the function stan_glm() in R?

Tags: r, rstanarm

when i use stan_glm(), i dont know how to change my interval.

my code:

```html
mod_rstan <- stan_glm(
    formula = f,
    data = dat,
    family = gaussian(), 
    prior_intercept = normal(0, 10),
    prior = normal(0, 2.5),
    prior_aux = cauchy(0, 5),
    cores = 3,
    chains = 3,
    iter = 2000)
     s_rstan <- summary(mod_rstan)
```

I get a result as the following picture showing：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtNi8.png)

how can we change the interval from 10% to 2.5% and the another from 90% to 97.5%?

Comment: It's in the documentation, `summary(example_model, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))`

Answer (score 1):

The estimation of the credible interval for the coefficients is performed in the `summary` call, not the `stan_glm` call. You can adjust the width of the interval with the argument `probs`, `summary(example_model, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))`.

Comment: oh, thank u very much.  I made mistakes in direction

Comment: Also `posterior_interval(mod_rstan, prob = 0.95)`. However, the endpoints of a 95% credible interval are not estimated very precisely with the default arguments to the `stan_` fitting functions.